# Kivymd Custom List Dialog. can't insert changeable list in mddialog

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, mddialog

I'm trying to add a changeable list in a custom dialog in kivyMD. the problem is when I call `self.adding()` , the list appears in my `FloatLayout`, not in the dialog.
I know that's because I called "Content" in my `FloatLayout`. I did this because I wanted to use ObjectProperty but it didn't work well. I really don't know what can I do to solve this problem.

Sorry for my broken English.

**code:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem,MDList
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

KV = '''
<Content>
    name:"content"
    draw:container
    orientation: "vertical"
    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: container


FloatLayout:
    mgr:cont
    Content:
        id:cont
        
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_confirmation_dialog()
'''


class Content(BoxLayout):
    draw=ObjectProperty(None)


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    mgr=ObjectProperty(None)
    def adding(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.root.mgr.draw.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}"))


    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)



    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
        # def adding(self):
        #     for i in range(20):
        #         container.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}"))
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Address:",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
            )
        self.adding()
        self.dialog.open()


Example().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by editing my code to this :

**NEW CODE:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem,MDList

KV = '''
<Content>
    # name:"content"
    # draw:container
    orientation: "vertical"
    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: container


FloatLayout:
    # mgr:cont
    # Content:
    #     id:cont
        
    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_confirmation_dialog()
'''


class Content(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.container= self.ids.container
        print("content called")
        def adding(self):
            for i in range(20):
                self.container.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}"))
            print("adding called")
        adding(self)


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None


    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Address:",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
            )

        self.dialog.open()


Example().run()
```